# Can you override the truthy coercion of a JavaScript Object?

Tags: javascript, object, coercion

The `string` coercion can be overwritten using the `toString` function.

The `number` coercion can be overwritten using the `valueOf` function.

The `boolean` coercion can be also overwritten using the `valueOf` function.

```js
var foo = {
  toString: function() {
    console.log("To String");
    return "bar";
  },
  valueOf: function() {
    console.log("Value Of");
    return 5;
  }
};

console.log(`${foo}`);
console.log(+foo);
console.log(foo == true);
console.log(!!foo);
```

I haven't been able to find a function that gets called for when an object needs to get converted to a `truthy`. Since `x == true` and `!!x` have different behaviors, then I am guessing that there is no function that changes that. I instead tried extending types whose `truthy` is `false` but the only value that gets accepted by `Object.create` is `null` which is almost identical to an object literal (has none of the `Object.prototype` properties).

Comment: The short answer is JavaScript does not have actual operator overloading, so there is no way to modify certain behaviors in the language specification since it's essentially a hardcoded behavior. One such example is the negation operator.

Comment: you might be able to alter the way a window property coerces, but not the actual object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`foo == true` actually converts `foo` to a number, that's why `valueOf` works, but it's misleading.
[You can try `{} == true` here](https://felix-kling.de/js-loose-comparison/) to see which steps of the comparison algorithm are executed (disclaimer: I made that).

[`!foo`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-logical-not-operator) however calls [`ToBoolean`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-toboolean), which explicitly always returns `true` for an object. There is no way to override that behavior.

[image]

Comment: So if you do `var obj = {valueOf: function(){ return true; }}; console.log(obj == true)`, `true` will be converted to `1` and then back to `true`?

Comment: Both `true`s will be converted to `1`.

Comment: so the expression is coerced to `1 == 1`?

Comment: Yep. You can try it on the page I linked to.

Comment: Isn't `obj` supposed to be coerced to the same type as the `true` though?

Comment: `true` is converted to a number first. Again, if you try it out on the site I linked to you can see how the comparison algorithm is invoked recursively and which steps of the algorithm are executed.

Comment: This is the part i dont understand `x == ToNumber(y)`. `!!ToNumber(x) == y` or `ToBoolean(x) == y` seems simpler.

Comment: I don't make the rules (or the ECMAScript spec) :)

Comment: Fair enough, great site though